# I have a JSON object that is dymanic in length, need to process it

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON response that comes like this ::

```
   {
    "abc": [{
        "statsFetchDate": 1463961600000,
        "facebookLikes": 0,
        "facebookComments": 0,
        "facebookShares": 0,
        "twitterShares": 0,
        "linkedInShares": null,
        "instagramLikes": null,
        "instagramComments": null,
        "engagement": null,
        "velocity": 50710.29999999996
    }, {
        "statsFetchDate": 1464048000000,
        "facebookLikes": 0,
        "facebookComments": 0,
        "facebookShares": 0,
        "twitterShares": 0,
        "linkedInShares": null,
        "instagramLikes": null,
        "instagramComments": null,
        "engagement": null,
        "velocity": 473968.7000000002
    }],
    "def": [{
        "statsFetchDate": 1463961600000,
        "facebookLikes": 0,
        "facebookComments": 0,
        "facebookShares": 0,
        "twitterShares": 0,
        "linkedInShares": null,
        "instagramLikes": null,
        "instagramComments": null,
        "engagement": null,
        "velocity": 50710.29999999996
    }, {
        "statsFetchDate": 1464048000000,
        "facebookLikes": 0,
        "facebookComments": 0,
        "facebookShares": 0,
        "twitterShares": 0,
        "linkedInShares": null,
        "instagramLikes": null,
        "instagramComments": null,
        "engagement": null,
        "velocity": 473968.7000000002
    }]
}
```

i need to plot graphs for each of the object that comes, ie abc and def in this case, but the json objects are dynamic in nature and i can get multiple objects, how can i parese through each of them and process them for example here i need to access abc.stats fetch date and velocity and also def.stats fetch date and velocity, it will be a multiple line chart, plotting is not a tension but how can i parse through mutiple JSON objects?

Comment: Possibilities include, [for..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in), [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [for..of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) if you make the object iterable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the code below which will `console.log` the each `statsFetchDate` in your nested JSON.
Check [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zyLkdwmv/)

```js
var obj = {
  "abc": [{
    "statsFetchDate": 1463961600000,
    "facebookLikes": 0,
    "facebookComments": 0,
    "facebookShares": 0,
    "twitterShares": 0,
    "linkedInShares": null,
    "instagramLikes": null,
    "instagramComments": null,
    "engagement": null,
    "velocity": 50710.29999999996
  }, {
    "statsFetchDate": 1464048000000,
    "facebookLikes": 0,
    "facebookComments": 0,
    "facebookShares": 0,
    "twitterShares": 0,
    "linkedInShares": null,
    "instagramLikes": null,
    "instagramComments": null,
    "engagement": null,
    "velocity": 473968.7000000002
  }],
  "def": [{
    "statsFetchDate": 1463961600000,
    "facebookLikes": 0,
    "facebookComments": 0,
    "facebookShares": 0,
    "twitterShares": 0,
    "linkedInShares": null,
    "instagramLikes": null,
    "instagramComments": null,
    "engagement": null,
    "velocity": 50710.29999999996
  }, {
    "statsFetchDate": 1464048000000,
    "facebookLikes": 0,
    "facebookComments": 0,
    "facebookShares": 0,
    "twitterShares": 0,
    "linkedInShares": null,
    "instagramLikes": null,
    "instagramComments": null,
    "engagement": null,
    "velocity": 473968.7000000002
  }]
}
var objKeys = Object.keys(obj)
for (var i = 0, len = objKeys.length; i < len; i++) {
  for (var y = 0, len = obj[objKeys[i]].length; y < len; y++) {
    console.log(obj[objKeys[i]][y].statsFetchDate)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton!! i got the problem now.. :D

Answer (score 0):

Cycle the object using the keys, without knowing how many objects there are.

```
for(var key in object){
    //first key will be "abc", second "def"
    //object[key] will return the current object content
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To process the above data structure you need to do the following steps.

**1. parse the JSON string**

```
var oJSON = JSON.parse(jsonResponseString);
```

**2. iterate over the (dynamic) object properties**

```
for (var prop in oJSON) {
    if (oJSON.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        var aData = oJSON[prop]; // aData will be "abc" for example
        // do something with the array
    }
}
```

You need to check the properties with `hasOwnProperty` to avoid accessing inherited properties like `toString()`.
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty

**3. do your plotting on the data**

```
// For example
aData.forEach(function(dataPoint) {
    // dataPoint is an object
    plotPoint(dataPoint.statsFetchDate, dataPoint.velocity);
});

// alternative
for (var i = 0; i < aData.length; i++) {
    var dataPoint = aData[i]; // This is an object
    plotPoint(dataPoint.statsFetchDate, dataPoint.velocity);
}
```